# Bounding probability measures by Wasserstein distance

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\nu$ and $\mu$ be probability measures of full-support over a compact metric space $(E,r)$. 
For every $\delta>0$ consider the open balls $B(x,\delta)$ for $x\in E$.

I want to show that 
$$
\sup_{x\in E} |\nu(B(x,\delta)) -\mu(B(x,\delta))|
\leq C \times d_{Pr}(\nu,\mu),
$$
with $C$ an independent constant and $d_{Pr}$ denotes the Prokhorov distance.

The first thing I tried is to split the space due to compactness by union of open balls of diameter bounded by the Prokhorov distance, this obviously does not work because the "constant" is a function of the Prokhorov distance.

Then I thought I could use the Wasserstein distance that can be written as 
$$
d_W(\nu, \mu)=
\sup_{||h|| \in Lip(1)}{|\int h d\nu - \int h d\mu |},
$$
where $Lip(1)$ denotes the Lipschitz functions with Lipschitz constant less than one.

I have tried to bound it by Lipschitz functions of Lipschitz constant 1, so I can use that the Wasserstein distance can be compared to the Prokhorov distance. However I noticed that while Indicators of can be approximated by Lipschitz functions, it is not true that they can be approximated by Lip(1).

Clearly $f\leq 1_B \leq g$ for some $f,g$ Lipschitz of constant one. Namely, just take $g$ as $1_B$ and interpolate linearly the endpoints, and take $f=1_{B(x,\delta/4)}$ and interpolate linearly the endpoints. Thus

$$
|\nu(B)-\mu(B)|
\leq
|\int g d\nu - \int f d\mu|,
$$

I have done some manipulations but I cannot get something like 
$$
|\nu(B)-\mu(B)|
\leq
|\int g d\nu - \int g d\mu|+
|\int f d\nu - \int f d\mu|.
$$

Any advice is warmly welcome.

Comment: Doesn't this follow immediately from the definition of Prokhorov definition [given on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric) (take $A=B(x,\delta)$, $C=1$)?  Are you using a different definition?